# Can AWS Certificate Manager (ACM) Certificates be used on Elastic Load Balancer Instances in Regions other than us-east-1?

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl-certificate, elastic-beanstalk

Amazon has recently announced their new AWS Certificate Manager (ACM) service. This looks promising, but it is currently only supported in the us-east-1 region.

I have existing resources in the us-west-2 region. Is it possible for me to create a certificate using ACM, and then use it on an ELB instance in us-west-2? Or do I have to wait for Amazon to roll the service out to other regions? The [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/acm/latest/userguide/acm-regions.html) is frustratingly vague on this point.

(Possibly) Related questions:

- [Can I use the new free SSL/TLS AWS certificates without ELB or Beanstalk on plain EC2?](https://serverfault.com/questions/751209/can-i-use-the-new-free-ssl-tls-aws-certificates-without-elb-or-beanstalk-on-plai)
- [Passing multiple https domains through Elastic Load Balancer](https://serverfault.com/questions/751435/passing-multiple-https-domains-through-elastic-load-balancer/751455#751455)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Not as of now, no.

The answer to the question is slightly hidden, under an entirely *different* question in the ACM FAQ:

> **Q: Can I use the same certificate in more than one AWS Region?**
>
> It depends on whether you’re using Elastic Load Balancing or Amazon CloudFront. **If you want to use a certificate with Elastic Load Balancing for the same site (the same fully qualified domain name, or FQDN, or set of FQDNs) in a different Region (when ACM is available in additional Regions), you will be required to request a new certificate for each Region in which you plan to use it.** Certificates issued in the US East (Northern Virginia) Region and associated with an Amazon CloudFront distribution are distributed to the geographic locations configured for your distribution. *(emphasis added)*
>
> https://aws.amazon.com/certificate-manager/faqs/

From that, we can safely conclude that the service can't be used for ELBs outside us-east-1, until such time as the service is deployed in the respective regions.

The [AWS Global Infrastructure pages](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/global-infrastructure/regional-product-services/) show the service only being available (as of this writing) in us-east-1.

The apparent discrepancy between in-region-only availability for ELB, compared with global availability with CloudFront, is explained by the fact that us-east-1 is the region that houses the infrastructure that actually controls the provisioning of all CloudFront edge locations.

Comment: Finding this earlier would have saved me a lot of time. I read through the  documentation, but the wording was ambiguous enough to make me think I might be mistake. The limitation is a real shame.

Comment: @brice I'm sure they will be launching it in other regions in a reasonable period of time.  I've been using this in us-west-2 by using CloudFront, which -- because of the bandwidth pricing structure -- is essentially zero cost. The CF cache can be disabled.  If you need SSL between CloudFront and the ELB or instance, you can use a wildcard cert you already have on hand, or get a cheap cert from, say, Gandi (no affiliation, but they give you a free 1 year cert for each domain you register), to use on the back-end connection.  Or run HTTP between CF and EC2, but HTTPS to the browser.

Comment: Thanks @Michael, Your suggestion worked great. I'm still testing to make sure that cloudfront isn't interfering with the requests, but it looks like that was a winner.

Comment: I had that concern initially, @brice but so far it's behaved perfectly -- be mindful of forwarding cookies, query strings, and headers appropriately and I wouldn't expect issues.  When you get more comfortable with the idea, then try adding cache behaviors matching static file paths like `*.css` with cookies, query strings, and appropriate headers *not* forwarded, enable automatic content compression, and save bandwidth while improving page loads.

Answer (score 2):

This now works, I requested a certificate from Certificate Manager and assigned to my US West (Oregon) Elastic Load Balancer. I added an EC2 instance to the ELB and had the ELB point to port 80 on the EC2 instance, not port 443 (this is some what faster I suppose). The ELB will then encrypt the connection between the user and the EC2 instance.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible for me to create a certificate using ACM, and then use
>   it on an ELB instance in us-west-2?

Yes, as you can see [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/rande.html#acm_region) from official documentation, the ACM is now supported in other regions.